# Rubyzip and zipruby for zip/unzip not creating much difference in the compressed zipfile size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, zip, rubyzip

i have been using `rubyzip` for zip/unzip for files/folder ranging from 20MB TO 1GB.i noticed that after zipping a folder of 20MB,the created zipfile is almost of the same size somewhat 20MB.So is `rubyzip` just zip the file or actually compresses it because the compressed file must be less than 40%-50% of the actual file size.i even tried using `system(zip, archive, Dir["#{path}/**/**"])` but i guess i am unable to get the correct syntax to call it.So my questions are

1. why `rubyzip` is unable to create an actual zip file which must be less in size too.
2. for a zipfile of more than 500MB,how van i send it to the client using send_file because its going to cost performance issue for a file of that size.what if i place that zip of 500MB or above in public folder and let the server serve it which might improve the performance,am i correct?
3. are there any other option instead of using `rubyzip/zipruby`(which requires libraries too).

I am using ruby 1.9 and rails 2.3.

my code:-

```
require 'zip/zip'
require 'fileutils'
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'


def self.compress_test(path)

    path="#{RAILS_ROOT/answers/}"  
     path.sub!(%r[/$],'')
     archive = File.join(path,File.basename(path))+'.zip'
     FileUtils.rm archive, :force=>true
     Zip::ZipFile.open(archive, 'w') do |zipfile|
       Dir["#{path}/**/**"].reject{|f|f==archive}.each do |file|
             begin  
                 zipfile.add(file.sub(path+'/',''),file)   
             rescue Zip::ZipEntryExistsError
             end
       end
     end
 end
```

Comment: Compression ratios depend a *lot* on the type of file. What type of files are in the folder with total size 20MB?

Comment: The folder struture is like this parent/child1 child2 and so on upto 100 and child folders will have files that can be xls,zip,txt file where one parent folder will have a collection o folder each of approx 3-5MB.

Comment: If you compress a folder of zip files, the resulting file will *not* be smaller.

Comment: Thanks Neil for the quick reply.its not always that there will be zip files.I have created a folder having static images,xls files to test but after compression using above code the size of the zip is almost the same.

Comment: `xls` files should compress a little (maybe to 50% of original), but `jpg`, `png` or `gif` will not (they are already compressed inside, you'll get 99% original size or similar) - the images are usually larger files than the spreadsheets, so you probably won't notice in the total file size.

Comment: Thanks Neil,so if a folder of 11.5 MB with files of txt,images and xls gives a zip of 9.1MB,so is it the best that i can get or there are other options to further reduce by again zipping the newly created zip(which you said wont be useful).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why rubyzip is unable to create an actual zip file which must be less in size too.

This varies a lot depending on what files you are trying to compress. Text and xls files will compress reasonably well. Media files in formats like JPEG, PNG, MPEG etc are *already* compressed internally, and often get compression ratios of 99%. They will usually be bigger that other files in the same folder, so the result of compressing a folder with some images, text and spreadsheets will not seem much smaller. Compressing a `.zip` file can even make the end result *larger* than you started.

> for a zipfile of more than 500MB,how van i send it to the client using
>   send_file because its going to cost performance issue for a file of
>   that size.what if i place that zip of 500MB or above in public folder
>   and let the server serve it which might improve the performance,am i
>   correct?

Yes, saving a large file to disk, and letting the web server send it may be more efficient. The easiest thing to do would be to save the file to a folder where it can be served from, and provide a link. You could also make that from a different server (e.g. a lighttpd instance dedicated to serving out the large files) to avoid loading your application server.

There are some setups that allow you to pass control back from a Ruby process to e.g. Apache ( `xsendfile` is one I know of ), but setting that up would be a different question, it depends what web server you have, and whether you have security concerns.

> are there any other option instead of using rubyzip/zipruby(which
>   requires libraries too).

Probably yes, but it is not likely you will find solutions to your two other questions by changing which gem you are using, because `rubyzip` is doing a reasonable job here - it is not failing.